# Visual Studio 2010 - Favour Size or Speed for optimization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, release

I came across the option C/C++ -> General -> Favour Size or Speed. 
I wanted to know if I choose the Speed option instead of size. Will their be any drawbacks to see other than the size. The default is neither. Will there be significant boost in speed of the application if I choose`Favor Fast Code /Ot`

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9534wye.aspx) should help you! I have used both in the past and using fast code has got some, but not drastic effect on your size. You have to be careful if you have a tight spec. on your resource utilisation.

Answer (score 1):

While I have no intimate knowledge regarding this compiler setting (I've generally favoured fast code and never thought about it again), I can see what this might affect:

On some processors, performing certain operations at certain times may incur stalls.  Things like accessing a full register (`RAX`) immediately after writing to part of it (`AL`), for example.  While modern processors can usually work around these stalls by reordering instructions, there are times when they are still unavoidable.

I suspect that through this setting the compiler may insert no-op instructions at times to try and prevent these stalls from occurring. Generally speaking, executing a few no-ops is still faster than stalling.

Obviously these no-ops will make your code larger, which may cause more instruction cache fetches (which could severely affect performance of very tight inner loops - but then again these are more likely to stall in the first place), but shouldn't have any other adverse effects.

The best advice I can offer to anyone with questions like this is to try different settings and run the code through a profiler and see if you're getting noticeably different results.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to optimize the code use relase build, If you are using the release build then Maximum speed(/O2) option is by default on and which is equivalent to Favour fast Code(/Ot)
2.Now, if you change Favor size or speed option to favor small code(/Os) which is bu default 'Neither', you could see drastic change in size of executable.

This might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt(v=vs.90).aspx